# Add with javascript a image extension to urls

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have some urls and I want to add the string **".webp"** in the alphanumeric id just before the parameter *&size*

```
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=xjfhob38jg8g&size=g&v=20210314224102
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=caucp0d8ig8o&size=g&v=20210309074045
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=9guq9t6e5fs1&size=g&v=20210318114201
```

I only get these strings so I have to add ".webp" somehow with javascript.

**I want this result:**

```
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=xjfhob38jg8g.webp&size=g&v=20210314224102
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=caucp0d8ig8o.webp&size=g&v=20210309074045
http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=9guq9t6e5fs1.webp&size=g&v=20210318114201
```

how can I do it? Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams

Answer (score 0):

```js
let temp = "http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=xjfhob38jg8g&size=g&v=20210314224102"

console.log(temp.slice(0, temp.indexOf("&size")) + ".webp" + temp.slice(temp.indexOf("&size")))
```

You can store the url first in a variable and then use slice to update the url.

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=xjfhob38jg8g&size=g&v=20210314224102'.replace(/&size/, '.webap&size'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let a ='http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icondsn=xjfhob38jg8g&size=g&v=20210314224102'
//your url

let url = a.replace('&size', '.webp&size'); 
//new url 'http://r.rp-static.pre/r/dsn-icon?dsn=xjfhob38jg8g.webp&size=g&v=20210314224102'
```